# See TFS Scrum Tools using only PBI and Bugs only?

Tags: tfs, vsts

I have recently joined a new software development company and they currently use TFS to create PBI's and Bugs and they do not include tasks. I want to be able to utilise the scrum tools available in TFS (2013) so as I can see burndown charts and metrics etc. Is there any way to tap into these tools without using tasks? I want to see if this is possible before I start changing their process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your TFS project is using the "Scrum" process template.

You could create another project (or modify the current one - which is harder depending on the TFS version that you have) and use the "Agile" process template that has User Stories (instead of PBI), burndown chart in the Iteration overview, and other definitions.

How to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/update-customized-process-template?view=vsts

Comment: Thank you for this, that link has taken me exactly where I needed to go. I will look into the Agile Template too to see if this might be the answer for us. Otherwise we may need to customize our process template so as the information attributed to the PBI's (feature requests) and Bugs (defects) appear in the reporting. I want to see the estimated time, assigned developers etc in the reporting which is currently only tapped into when we create tasks within PBI's & bug's. It may not be possible to do what we want but I can have a developer look into it now for me! Create my own user story :)

Comment: Note: we have already customised the PBI's and Bugs to hold all the information we need for other reporting we do for our stakeholders to a deployment site. So I want to keep these items as the only items we enter for a project. Adding tasks then is just duplication of effort within our current process.